# Can't position a modal frame in landscape but okay in portrait

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I have a view controller I'm trying to present modally. I need to move it to a specific location on screen. The code below works fine in portrait but in landscape the view doesn't reposition at all, no matter what point I set the center to. If I use pcvc.landscapeView.center instead of pcvc.landscapeView the view repositions but a gray box remains in the view's original position, and I can't interact with the view.

How do I need to treat view controllers differently when in landscape orientation?

```
PostCommentViewController *pcvc = [[PostCommentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PostCommentViewController" bundle:nil];
pcvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
pcvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:(UIViewController *)pcvc animated:YES completion:nil];
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
{
    pcvc.portraitView.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 750, 143);
    pcvc.portraitView.superview.center = CGPointMake(384, 680);
}
else
{
    pcvc.landscapeView.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 683, 300);
    pcvc.landscapeView.superview.center = CGPointMake(500, 60);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use 2 views?

Comment: They're different layouts but perform the same function, it's necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really can help with this small piece of code.
Your loading an xib file named `PostCommentViewController`
That xib file has 2 views `portraitView` and `landscapeView`
And your trying to move the superview so thats the view that contains `portraitView` and `landscapeView`.

I don't understand but as a quick fix, u can make a differs xib for different layout. 
Again i don't have your viewcontroller hierarchy, so its hard to help.

call this in didrotate

```
-(void)changeOrientation {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Portrait" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    else {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Landscape" owner:self options:nil];
    }

}
```